# graphviz dot: use the same angle for the text (label) as what is used for the arrow (edge), rather than default horizontal

Tags: graphviz, dot

Edge labels always seem to be horizontal. Is it possible to allign them to the arrow? In other words to use the same angle for the text as  what is used for the arrow.

```
 digraph A {
    splines=false;
    A->B [label="allign me with the angle of the arrow"];                                                   
    A->C;
 }
```

[image: example dot]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no.  There is a request on the books (https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/2007), but seemingly no active work on this.